Why does first-person view show a kaleidoscope-like glitch after character creation?
I've been encountering this glitch in Skyrim. After creating and naming a character and going into first person, I get this weird kaleidoscope-like glitch. Everything is fine in third-person view, but first-person is just unviewable. Can anyone help a guy out, please?

Can you include a picture of what you see? It would help a lot.
